# Why such polynomial equation $h(u,v)=-g(u,v)$ has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis, polynomials, field-theory

Let $\mathbf{F}_q$ be a finite field. Let $U, V\subseteq \mathbf{F}_q^s$ and all vectors in $U$ have distinct first coordinates, and all vectors in $V$ has distinct first coordinates too. Assume $r,s\le \sqrt{q}$. Let $g\in \mathbf{F}_q[X_1,...,X_s,Y_1,...,Y_s]$ be a fixed polynomial. Let $H=\{\sum_{0\le i\le s-1, 0\le j\le r-1} C_{ij}X_1^iY_1^j|C_{ij}\in \mathbf{F}_q\}$.

Then the statement is that there exists a unique $h\in H$ s.t. $h(u,v)=-g(u,v)$ for all $u\in U, v\in V$.

Someone explains it to me by using Lagrange interpolation theorem twice for $h(X,Y)$. But I am still not very clear. And why do we require all vectors in $U$ have distinct 1-coordinate, and similar for $V$?

Comment: I am clear now.